# Android Maven Plugin does not work

Tags: android, spring, maven-plugin

I´m trying to run the android greenhouse client with the android maven plugin and I got the following execption while trying to execute `mvn clean install`:

> `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:maven-android-plugin:2.8.4:dex (default-dex) on project greenhouse: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\lyth\Eigene Dateien\Downloads\android-sdk_r11-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\dx.bat" --dex "--output=C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\lyth\Eigene Dateien\Downloads\SpringSource-greenhouse-android-feff5a5\target\classes.dex" "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\lyth\Eigene Dateien\Downloads\SpringSource-greenhouse-android-feff5a5\target\android-classes"", Result = 255`

My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.springsource</groupId>
<artifactId>greenhouse</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>greenhouse-android</name>
<url>http://www.springsource.org</url>
<organization>
    <name>SpringSource</name>
    <url>http://www.springsource.org</url>
</organization>

<properties>
    <env>dev</env>
    <android-platform>7</android-platform>
    <android-emulator>7</android-emulator>
    <maven-resources-plugin-version>2.5</maven-resources-plugin-version>
    <maven-android-plugin-version>2.8.4</maven-android-plugin-version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin-version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    <maven-eclipse-plugin-version>2.8</maven-eclipse-plugin-version>
    <android-version>2.1_r1</android-version>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <spring-android-version>1.0.0.M4</spring-android-version>
    <spring-social-version>1.0.0.RC1</spring-social-version>
    <spring-security-version>3.1.0.RC2.crypto</spring-security-version>
    <jackson-version>1.8.3</jackson-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>${android-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-android-auth</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-android-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- exclude in favor of spring-android-core -->
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- exclude in favor of spring-android-rest-template -->
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <filters>
        <filter>${project.basedir}/filters/${env}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <!-- copy and filter all xml resource files -->
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/res</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/filtered-res</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <!-- copy only. do not filter non-xml resource files -->
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/res</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/filtered-res</targetPath>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <!-- copy and filter the Android Manifest file -->
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/filtered-manifest</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>AndroidManifest.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-resources-plugin-version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-android-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <androidManifestFile>${project.build.directory}/filtered-manifest/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/filtered-res</resourceDirectory>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>${android-platform}</platform>
                </sdk>
                <emulator>
                    <avd>${android-emulator}</avd>
                </emulator>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <env>dev</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <env>prod</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<repositories>
    <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: okay .. problem solved .. it was because of the whitespaces in the path ..

Comment: Close the question or provide the answer as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

> okay .. problem solved .. it was because of the whitespaces in the
>   path .. –  Christine Bauers Aug 11 '11